# Why IIS 7.5 (Running .Net 4.5 web API) gives error when Date Time sent containing UTC as timezone

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I am working on a project, which mainly deals with **DateTime**. It runs on **Windows 2008 R2**, using **.Net 4.5 MVC Web API**  and **IIS version 7.5.7600.16385**.

So far, when I was testing it on **Chrome** and **FireFox**, it worked very well. But when I started testing on **Internet Explorer**, it start giving **Model Error** about **DateTime** field.

**Error was:** The value `Tue, 23 Mar 2013 12:00:00 UTC` is not valid for StartTime.

However, I figured out **the solution**. I have replaced the `UTC` with `GMT` in every **DateTime** field, then its just works fine.

**Solution in practice:**

Value creating Error: `Tue, 23 Mar 2013 12:00:00 UTC`

Solution: `Tue, 23 Mar 2013 12:00:00 GMT`

This way it works well, I guess Problem and Solution is Clear, now my question is:

**Question:** Why does **IIS** give error with DateTime string format containing `UTC` as Time Zone?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am not sure why you need UTC and GMT.

Might be this is the reason IE is getting more smarter these days ;)

> Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is a term originally referring to mean solar
>   time at the Royal Observatory, Greenwich where a system was first
>   developed around 1850 for tracking time based on the rotation of the
>   Earth. It is now often used to refer to Coordinated Universal Time
>   (UTC) when this is viewed as a time zone.
>
> Strictly speaking, UTC is not a time zone but an atomic time scale
>   which only approximates GMT in the old sense. It is also used to refer
>   to Universal Time (UT), which is the astronomical concept that
>   directly replaced the original GMT.

As UTC is not a time zone so IE is not converting it, however other browsers are flexible and intelligent enough.

Comment: Yes that's may be the reason IE doing this, but the question is Why IIS not working with UTC?

Comment: IE and IIS comes from same vendor or might be from same development team.
Anyways that might be policy of Microsoft, if it would have been vice versa then it would be interesting.

Comment: Yes this could be the reason, because on previous server it just worked fine, So the change must be done by IIS developers in IIS and I am looking for a solution which makes IIS accept UTC, there should be some trigger, because it worked fine in past.